# How to change the mathematical symbol class of a unicode math symbol?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, mathcode

In `unicode-math-table.tex` the math class of many symbols is defined by lines like:

`\UnicodeMathSymbol{"026AC}{\mdsmwhtcircle}{\mathord}{medium small white circle}%`

Now if I want to use this particular circle as binary operator for function composition I have to change its math class to `\mathbin`. What I would like to do in the preamble is something like:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"026AC}{\mdsmwhtcircle}{\mathbin}{medium small white circle}%`
```

Thereby overwriting `unicode-math’s` defaults. However the marco `\UnicodeMathSymbol` seems only to be available internally, when `unicode-math` processes `unicode-math-table.tex`.

Of course I can copy `unicode-math-table.tex` to a local texmf-tree, modify it and achieve the desired result. But I would prefer to keep this change local to the document and make the change in the preamble.

How can I overwrite `unicode-math’s` defaults with regard to the symbols math class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two choices; one is easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\newcommand{\bcirc}{\mathbin{\mdsmwhtcircle}}

\begin{document}
$f\bcirc g$
\end{document}
```

The second one is more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \um_process_symbol_noparse:nnn {"026AC}{\mdsmwhtcircle}{\mathbin}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$f\mdsmwhtcircle g$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately there is apparently no higher level tool for setting symbols.

Comment: The second solution is what I am looking for. I can just write f⚬g and get the correct spacing. No command sequences needed.

Comment: Just a quick note, the latest changes to `unicode-math` have changed the internal command used in the second solution. it should now be `\__um_process_symbol_noparse:nnn` (the command is prefixed with a double underscore.

Comment: @ArTourter Which makes it a private command. `:-(` There should be some interface to associate a Unicode point to a command with the math type.

Comment: @egreg I am not quite sure what the fact that it has become a private command actually entails. Your solution still works.